# Save "custom-set-variables" with elisp

Tags: emacs, customization

If I bring up emacs' customization interface, edit a variable, and then set+save it, its new value gets stored in a `(custom-set-variables ...)` list in my init file.

Now, let's say I modified a variable's value in elisp (using `(setq ...)` or something else).

How can I save this new value to the `(custom-set-variables ...)` list **using elisp** instead of the interactive interface?

Comment: I know I canb just write the `(setq` command to my init file, but thats's not what I'm looking for. I need an automated method for saving the variable.

Comment: The default behavior is to not list variables defined with `setq` when saving custom set variables with the user interface; and, those `setq` variables cannot generally be overwritten through the user-interface.  For variables set by hand that will be saved with the user interface, you would actually need to use the same format within your elisp code -- i.e., the same format you see after saving with the user interface.  Long story short, if you used `setq` -- you cannot get there from here -- unless you use a new `setq` that loads after the prior `setq` effectively redefining it.

Comment: The magic is occurring with `.../lisp/cus-edit.el` and `.../lisp/custom.el`

Comment: @lawlist I know setq takes priority over custom set variables, but that's not a problem here. I mentioned the variable was edited with setq, but this setq isn't written in the configuration file (which is exactly why I need an automated way of saving this modification permanently).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like you are looking for `customize-save-variable`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `customize-save-variable` is your friend.  See also http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CustomizingAndSaving about the relation between (a) making changes to options and faces and (b) saving them.

Answer (score 0):

The value of `custom-file' says where your customizations are stored. It's a plain Emacs Lisp, e.i. text file. You may change the values there from any program, creating an elisp command or change it from outside via sed, perl, python, emacs-batch mode etc.

Comment: True, but there had to be something easier (and less risky) than manually parsing the custom-file.